# update image in parallel with audio in pyqt5

Tags: python, image, pyqt, pyqt5

So my code goes like this:

```
def play_audio(self):
    sd.play(self.audio, self.fs) # sd is from 'import sounddevice as sd'
    count = 0
    while get_current_time() != 0.0:
        # current time is a function I did that gives 0.0 if audio finished playing and 
        # another float of the second the audio playing is currently on (if it haven't finished of course)
        if self.data.dat[count][0] <= self.data.get_current_index():
            # while some conditions (in a 2.5 seconds audio this updates 6 times more or less)
            update_label(self.data.dat[count][1].name)
            count = count + 1
```

Now the 'update_label' function does this:

```
def update_label(self, phoneme_name):
    pixmap = self.dict[phoneme_name]
    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

    self.label.update()
```

The self.dict is a dictionary that contains QPixmap (I'm using pyqt5).
The image should change then 6 times in 2.5 seconds but it only updates the last image once I'm outside the loop.

Comment: Try putting `QApplication.processEvents()` at the end of `update_label`.

Comment: Thak you @ekhumoro, that solved the problem!